# sqlite3 in asynchronous program with to_thread raises SystemErrors

Tags: python, sqlite, python-asyncio

I created a class that handles my sqlite database in python. This is written in synchronous code. Now, I want to use this code in an asynchronous program.
I used `asyncio.to_thread` to execute a database insert asynchronously.
However, I get different `SystemError` messages everytime I run my code.

Below, you find a minimal example which raises System errors.

There are easy workarounds to this, but I thought sqlite was threadsafe?
It took me a while to isolate the problem and I want to understand what is wrong, so I don't run into the same problems later on.
I use python3.11 and sqlite3 version=2.6 and sqlite3.threadsafe is 3

```py
import asyncio
import sqlite3
from pathlib import Path

Path("test.db").unlink(missing_ok=True)
con = sqlite3.connect("test.db", check_same_thread=False)


def init():
    con.execute("""CREATE TABLE test (test INTEGER NOT NULL);""")


async def write():
    while True:
        with con:
            con.execute("""INSERT INTO test VALUES (1) """)
        await asyncio.sleep(0)


async def write2():
    while True:
        await asyncio.to_thread(write3)


def write3():
    with con:
        con.execute("""INSERT INTO test VALUES (2) """)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    init()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.create_task(write())
        loop.create_task(write2())
        loop.run_forever()
    finally:
        con.commit()
        con.close()
        loop.close()
```